SELECTing an array from an array?
I'm getting an array of values as part of a query:
SELECT class_id, count(*) as num_in_class, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT major_id) major_ids
    FROM students GROUP BY class_id;

This gives me the number of distinct majors in each class.  The id of the major isn't super helpful though, I would like to know the name of the major:
SELECT major.name, ...
    ...
JOIN major on major.id = major_id

This naive solution doesn't work as is because my major_ids are in an array.  How can I complete this join and get the names of the majors into an array major_names of the same length as major_ids?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

@jarlh MREs only make sense in the context of bugs.  I do not have a bug.  I can provide an expected output.  I can also provide some code that does something completely different, and explain the difference.  Would you find that one of these might help make the problem statement more clear?

We don't know the tables, their columns, the data or the expected result.

Exact table definitions are practically always relevant. As is the version of Postgres.

Its basically the same that you are proposing with the join
select class_id, count(*) as num_in_class, 
array_agg(distinct array[m.id::varchar, m.name]) majors
from students s 
inner join major m on m.id =s.major_id  
group by class_id;

Fiddle to test

Do you just want something like this query?
SELECT
    s.class_id,
    COUNT(*) AS students_in_class,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT m.id) AS distinct_major_ids,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT m.name) AS distinct_major_names
FROM students s
INNER JOIN major m ON m.id = s.major_id
GROUP BY s.class_id;


The major ids might not be unique to a name.  So, there may be two "Mathematics" majors, one entry is for those starting in 2023 and one for those in 2024.

Well, okay.. the question does not mention it and also asks for the names instead of ids.. I guess this is what the query provides. If you need the names paired with the ids, you already found the answer by Pepe N O

Convert after aggregation
To "select an array from an array", you would have to unnest, join, and aggregate back. You can do that. It even makes sense sometimes, as a convenient drop-in. You might encapsulate the functionality in a function, like:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_convert_major_id_array(int[])
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN ARRAY(SELECT m.name FROM unnest($1) id JOIN major m USING (id));

Related:

How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?
What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?

Then:
SELECT class_id, count(*) AS num_in_class
     , f_convert_major_id_array(array_agg(DISTINCT major_id)) AS majors
FROM   students
GROUP  BY 1;

Or (faster):
SELECT class_id, sum(ct) AS num_in_class
     , f_convert_major_id_array(array_agg(major_id)) AS majors
FROM  (
   SELECT class_id, major_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   students
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) s
GROUP  BY 1;

Convert before aggregation
Typically faster.
SELECT class_id, sum(ct) AS num_in_class, array_agg(m.name) AS majors
FROM  (
   SELECT class_id, major_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   students
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) s
LEFT   JOIN major m ON m.id = s.major_id
GROUP  BY 1
-- ORDER  BY 1  -- optional
;

fiddle
Also, aggregate majors per class in table students before joining to table major to reduce join operations. That's typically fastest. Proof:
fiddle
To get a particular sort order among rows and/or array items, you have to do more. You didn't specify.
LEFT JOIN to preserve all students, even if some might have no major_id, yet (students.major_id IS NULL).
